# Add texts with line breaks in Win32 API ListView

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the WC_LISTVIEW control to create a table that is filled with data at runtime. The table is working fine. However, I cannot display multiple lines in one cell.

Is there a way to use line breaks (e.g. with `\n`)?

This is how I create the table:

```
HWND listViewErrors = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, L"",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | LVS_SINGLESEL,
    17, 27, errorsRect.Width() - 12, errorsRect.Height() - 25,
    GetWindowHandle(), (HMENU)ID_LIST_ERRORS, NULL, 0);
```

I add rows like this:

```
LVITEM lvi = { 0 };

lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
lvi.pszText = L"Label of an entry";

int ret = ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, &lvi); // Main item

if (ret >= 0)
{
    ListView_SetItemText(
            hwndList,
            ret,
            1,
            L"A description containing\nline breaks, but the\nline breaks will be\nignored."); // Sub item
}

return ret;
```

The result is that the line break character (`\n`) is not visible anymore, but the text is still in a single line.

[image]

Comment: Implementing this with owner draw as suggested by xMRi, can be challenging. You would have to calculate item heights dynamically, which will change when columns are resized, for instance. Alternatively stick with single-line text and set `LVS_EX_LABELTIP` to show text that doesn't fit in the column, as a tooltip (not sure if the tooltip supports line breaks though). Instead of a tooltip you could also add a read-only edit control that would always be visible and show the full text on selection change and/or mouse-over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you use custom draw or owner-draw, a LISTVIEW window never supports multi-line entries in report mode.

Even when using use custom draw or owner-draw, all rows will have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

What @xMRi said is right.

To make WC_LISTVIEW support multi-line text:

1. you should set it have LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED style. After this, you could see the ListView's content is invisible, although its header and grid line is visible.
2. At this time, ListView's parent window will receive WM_MEASUREITEM message.
   In my test, this message is received only one time. When received it, set the row height like this:

```
LRESULT DialogMain::OnMeasureItem(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lp = (LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

    //3 times of origin text height
    lp->itemHeight *= 3;

    return 0;
}
```

3. When repaint, ListView's parent window will receive WM_DRAWITEM message. Each row is corresponding one message.

In WM_DRAWITEM message, draw the text manually like this:

```
LRESULT DialogMain::OnDrawItem(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpdis = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;

    if (lpdis->CtlID != IDC_LISTVIEW)
        return 0;

    HDC hdc = lpdis->hDC;
    int index = lpdis->itemID;

    for (int col = 0; col < listView.GetColumnCount(); ++col)
    {
        string s = listView.GetItem(index, col);

        RECT rc = listView.GetGridRect(index, col);

        DrawText(hdc, (LPSTR)s.c_str(), s.length(), &rc, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice: my method can only make ListView's every row height be fixed.

[effect example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbmqv.png)